# Image Perspective Transformations

Tags: image-processing, geometric-transform

I'm trying to detect the license plate in these types of images which may be captured from various perspectives and lighting

[image]

I've found it easiest to detect these two points corresponding to the bottom corners of the blue box

[image]

Since my camera is always at a fixed height and the blue box is a fixed size, I'm thinking it's possible to determine the image perspective just from those two points. Then I can formulate a mapping that takes in the location of the two points and identifies the plate position.

I've had some luck labelling the plates on a few images and doing a linear regression to find the mapping from blue box corners to plate. I'm not very familiar with the math of perspective transforms and I'm not sure if the linear mapping is sufficient to capture the complexity.

I know Mathematica has functions such as `FindGeometricTransform` and `ImagePerspectiveTransformation`, I'm wondering if they could somehow be applied for this problem? Also if someone has a better idea to directly find the plate here's a test image

[image]
note that the lighting may change, but the hue's should be constant.

Thanks

Comment: It should be possible but you’ll probably need four points because the transformation has eight degrees of freedom.